# Alignment problem in tabularx that happens when I change it to non-decimal

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, tabularx

I have the following code which aligns when I have decimal figures but fails to do so when I type 0 for instance.

The code is as follow

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
    \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
    \usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \noindent 
    \newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X} 
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYY S[table-format=1.4] @{}}  

    \toprule 

    \thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Passive Total Return} & {\thead{Value Weighted\\ Return Index}} & {\thead{Equal Weighted\\ Return Index}} \\

    \midrule  

    Momentum & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \addlinespace

    Size & 0 & 0.72 & 0.72 \\ \addlinespace  

    Value & 0 & 0.37 & 1.00 \\ \addlinespace  

    \bottomrule  

    \end{tabularx}
    \enddocument
```

This use to look like the following which aligns perfectly. [image]

However, having made a change to single digit, my code only aligns the zero unlike the second row, which I find quite strange. It looks as follows: [image]

Could someone please provide some advice please ?

Thank you

Comment: You have decimal alignment in the 4th column but in both tables the alignment in the third column is poor with the 0 being centred not in the "units column"  of the numeric entries in that column.

Answer (score 1):

You have decimal alignment in the 4th column but in both tables the alignment in the third column is poor with the 0 being centred not in the "units column" of the numeric entries in that column. It would be more consistent to specify both columns using an `S` column for decimal alignment.

Note that if you have an integer (such as 0 in your example) in a decimal aligned column it aligns in the "units" to the left of the decimal point in other rows, it is not centred.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

In MWE below is considered David  Carlisle comment and answer. Added value is off-topic:

- it is sufficient to define new commands only once
- for equal width of columns with number is used trick: column headers use `\multicolumn` with modified `X` column type

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}% for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcommand\mcxh[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{\thead{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

     \setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Category}
            &   \mcxh{Passive\\ Total Return} 
                &   \mcxh{Value Weighted\\ Return Index}  
                        &   \mcxh{Equal Weighted\\ Return Index}    \\
    \midrule
Momentum    & 0 & 0     & 0     \\ 
Size        & 0 & 0.72  & 0.72  \\ 
Value       & 0 & 0.37  & 1.00  \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```